# Derivative of a polynomial in finite fields

Tags: finite-fields

In *Introduction to finite fields and their applications* by R.Lidl, the definition of the derivative for a polynomial such that ($a_i\in GF(q)$)
$$f_{(x)}=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0$$

is
$$f_{(x)}=na_n*x^{n-1}+\cdots +a_1 $$

It is not clear what the term $na_n$ actually means. We already know that $a_n$ is a member of the field. However, it is not clear what $n$ means. It can be the polynomial representation or the power representation.

What is the correct definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$n a_n$ usually refers to the canonical group action of $\mathbb{Z}$ on the field you're considering, i.e.
$$n a_n = \underbrace{a_n + \ldots + a_n}_{n \text{ times}}$$

**EDIT:** If you insist on using a polynomial representation, maybe [this site](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FiniteField.html) can help.

Comment: Thank you. However [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56538/derivative-of-polynomial-in-gf9?rq=1), 2 is converted to the filed member and an FF multiplication is used.

Comment: It's the same thing because $2 = 1+1$.